# How can I re-use blocks of haml with arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I've been using HAML for over 10 years, and this simple use case continues to elude me.

Say I have the following haml code

```
- links.each do |link|
  = link_to link.url do
    %i.fa.fa-map
    = link.text
```

This block works while looping only, but imagine a situation where I want to reuse the block in multiple loops, or in multiple places in the HAML file. I do not currently know how to do that without creating a separate partial or helper. When the block is big enough, I often will create a partial, but often the block is small and a partial seems tedious overkill. Sometimes I have several blocks like this that I only want re-used in one HAML file.

I tried first to create this with `content_for` but it doesn't accept arguments and can't be cached.

My second attempt was with `capture_haml`, but I think that has to be called directly indide of HAML, not a ruby method. The following obviously fails for syntax reasons, but you see what I'm trying to do:

```rb
:ruby
  def entry_link(url, text)
    capture_haml(url, text) do |url, text|
      = link_to url do
        %i.fa.fa-map
        text
    end
  end
```

Update:

I was able to get this far, which is functional but ugly AF.

```
:ruby
  def entry_link(url, text)
    capture_haml(url, text) do |url, text|
      link_to url do
        haml_tag :i, {class: 'fa fa-map'}
        haml_concat(text)
      end
    end
  end


= entry_link('/', 'My Link')
```

The following would be a more acceptable syntax, but I get the strange error `undefined local variable or method` _hamlout'`

```
- def entry_link(url, text)
  - link_to url do
    %i.fa.fa-map
    text
```

Comment: This is really a problem that should either be solved with a helper method, decorators or partials. I don't think HAML or any other Ruby templating language has built in support for code resuse as thats not really the job of a templating language.

Comment: I'm not so sure. For one, the re-use case is scoped only to the HAML file itself, so helpers and partials for me in this case (as I've said) seem way overkill. The functionality I'm looking for is basically `content_for` that could accept arguments (and be cached). I work with React and JSX a lot, and this kind of method-based approach on the view object itself has made the view side so much more powerful.

Comment: I guess if you consider HAML only a templating language, then it seems reasonable to consider something like what I'm looking for as out of its purview. In that sense I guess I'm looking for much more than a templating language for my view code. But given that HAML has filters and helpers built-in and so much more, I haven't been seeing it simply as a templating language.

Comment: I like the idea of having a decorator for the view, but I'd still have to resort to partials or string-based html in order to get what I want. It wouldn't be haml, and it would be logically separated out from the view, which increases the complexity of visualizing and editing the view. But if I'm willing to use string-based html which I'm not inclined to, I can just define a method in the HAML file that takes args.

Comment: As far as I know neither ERB, Haml nor Slim have something like [macros](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html) which is why Rails has the system with partials and the captures helper built on top of the templating language. Ruby is flexible enough that you could actually write a method which defines a method in the scope of the view context to simulate a macro but thats really just asking for trouble IMHO.

Comment: @max I got something to work (see update) but it's not really acceptable. Didn't know about Twig or its macros, but that's basically what I was looking for.